# How to deal with League of Legends sound volume

Tags: league-of-legends

Everytime there is an update, Windows resets the volume level (in game and for the client).

**Is there a way to fix it ?**

Comment: I don't encounter this problem, so I can't give you the solution but I think there is one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config folder there is a file called persistedsettings.json that is getting recreated on launch. This is a new addition to their file system and I think the settings are in here.

Try moving this file out of the directory and replacing it with a config.ini file, which is used to load in game settings. I haven't had this problem since doing this.

Answer (score 2):

One way i am aware you can do this is by using LSI(League Summoner Information) which was one of the reasons i started using it actually, you can control at which volume LoL stays even after updates.

*There might be other ways*, but this is the one i use.